# mongodb database schema for many-users-application

Tags: mongodb, collections, namespaces, schema

Question: There is a tens of thousands of users (but less then 500K) in an application.

Solution: store every user's collection (10-20) in a separate users namespace (just one for every client) to save disk space by escaping from id 'column' of each user; speed up query time couse of small index of a namespace; reduce locked ratio (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1240); simplify sharding (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-939).

Is this ok? Or maybe I should use one general collection with a namespaces?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: So you're wondering if with your <500k users, if you should do sharding in order to speed up queries? Can you show your current document structure so that we have a general idea of what the user documents look like?

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your question, but correct me if I'm wrong. Seems like you're looking to store the users of each Application in their own collection. This has several advantages and disadvantages that you have to weight based on complex DBA decisions like R/W ratio, load, etc.

**Advantages**

- Like you've mentioned, indexes will take less time to update because they only have a segment of users.
- Queries on non indexed fields (if there are any)  will be quicker because of the smaller number of elements.
- The global write lock won't play as much of a role since you're only locking per application.

**Disadvantages**

- Since indexes are scoped by collection you will have (# of Applications) times more indexes to keep in memory (indexes do little good if you page them out).
- Because indexes and collections occupy their own namespaces and each namespace occupies about 628 bytes , you need to worry about the default [16MB namespace limit](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+a+Large+Number+of+Collections). This will limit the number of applications you can have. e.g. with 2 indexes you're limited to about 8,000 collections.
- Finally, since your users will be in different collections, you won't be able to query across applications. This can be subverted by MapReduce, but adds more complexity.

At the end of the day you can achieve most of these benefits while circumventing the disadvantages by simply sharding on some application key. The many collection scenario is tempting, but I think ultimately not what mongo is optimized for.

Comment: Yes, you understand right. So, how do you think. What mongo is optimized for? How should I do in this situation?

Comment: If you can afford to set up a couple shards (one shard is, generally speaking, a replica set consisting of three or more machines) you should do as I've noted in the final paragraph and not have a collection per application. Sharding on an application key would be ideal. If you're convinced you can keep all of your users and indexes in memory using only one replica set, and are not worried about the namespace limit, then I would suggest doing as you've stated in the question and breaking apart the apps into collections.